# Finding the index position of an array

Tags: javascript

```js
var cars = ["BMW", "BENZ", "LAMB", "AUDI"];
var abc = cars.indexOf("BMW");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = abc;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

This is the code where it displays the position but I want reverse of this that is if I enter a position it should display the array value. How to get that?

Comment: const index = yourIndex;  console.log(cars[index]);

Comment: document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cars[0]; No need of var abc here. This solved my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can access array element by referring to the index number. Use `array[index]` like following:

```js
var index = 0;
var cars = ["BMW", "BENZ", "LAMB", "AUDI"];
var abc = cars[index];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = abc;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```js
const cars = ["BMW", "BENZ", "LAMB", "AUDI"];
let indexIWant = 0;
document.getElementById("demo").innerText = cars[indexIWant];
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```